# How can i pass a html select tag (dropdown) value to the controller using jquery in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, select

I generated a `<select>` option from series of string arrays with `.Split()` method in my mvc application like below:

```
@{
   var ava = Model.AvailableSizes.Split(',').ToList();
 }
    <select class="form-control input-sm">
    <option>Select Size</option>
    @foreach (var item in ava)
       {
          <option>@item</option>
       }
    </select>
```

I would like to pass the selected value of this dropdownbox to the controller action method below:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddToCart(Cart cart, int productId, string returnUrl)
        {
            Product product = repository.Products
                        .FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductID == productId);

            if (product != null)
            {
                cart.AddItem(product, 1);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { returnUrl });
        }
```

How is it possible? Thank you for your time.
**Edit: @Stephen** I use repository instead of view model like below:

```
public ViewResult ProductDetails(int productId)
        {
            Product product = repository.Products
                .FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductID == productId);

            return View(product);
        }
```

How should i deal with that then?
**Edit2:@Stephen**
Here is the Cart Index Method:

```
public ViewResult Index(Cart cart, string returnUrl)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Dude, This gonna make it";
            return View(new CartIndexViewModel
            {
                ReturnUrl = returnUrl,
                Cart = cart
            });
        }
```

Comment: In the AddToCart method, get the value of the dropdown list.  `int selectedValue = Request.Form["input-sm"].AsInt();`

Comment: @Eric doesn't work

Comment: Do you put the `<select>` inside `<form>`?  If not, it won't post to the server.

Comment: You `<select>`element does not have a name attribute so it wont submit a name/value pair. Use the strongly typed `DropDownListFor()` method so you html is generated correctly

Comment: @StephenMuecke i can't style it then the way i want to using `DropDownListFor()`

Comment: Of course you can - `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.yourProperty, Model.yourSelectList, "Select Size", new { @class="form-control input-sm" })`. And code such as `var ava = Model.AvailableSizes.Split(',').ToList();` belongs in the controller, not the view.

Comment: +1 and what to be done next? would you please post it as an answer so i can accept the answer? Thanks a lot @StephenMuecke

Comment: Give me 30 min. Is `productId` the property your trying to bind to, or another value?

Comment: No it is the select value of the dropdown box want to pass it to AddToCart action method and then from there to another view called cart index. @StephenMuecke

Comment: Dear @StephenMuecke did you notice i generated this `<select>` options using `.Split()` method from series of string arrays?!

Comment: Yes. What is the property in your model that you want to bind the selected size to?

Comment: That is ProductID @StephenMuecke

Comment: 2 comments again you said, no it wasn't :)

Comment: Sorry couldn't catch if for the first time you asked, yes it is the productid, thank you! @StephenMuecke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `<select>` element does not have a `name` attribute so your form will not submit a name/value pair. You could solve this using

```
<select name="productId" class="form-control input-sm">
```

assuming `productId` is the value you want to bind to. But there are other issues with your code (for example you would start throwing exceptions is the user selected the first option) and you should be using a view model and the strongly typed `HtmlHelper` methods to generate your html correctly.

```
public class ProductVM
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ....
    [Display(Name = "Select size" )]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a size")]
    public int SelectedSize { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AvailableSizes { get; set; }
    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
}
```

and in the controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ViewResult ProductDetails(int productId)
{
    Product product = repository.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductID == productId);
    string[] sizes = product.AvailableSizes.Split(',');
    ProductVM model = new ProductVM()
    {
        ID = product.ProductId,
        Name = product.Name
        AvailableSizes = new SelectList(sizes),
        ReturnUrl = ....
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

and in the view

```
@model ProductVM
....
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    ....
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedSize)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedSize, Model.AvailableSizes, "Select Size", new { @class="form-control input-sm" }))
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedSize)
```

and finally in the POST method, include a parameter for the view model

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddToCart(Cart cart, ProductVM model)
```

and the value of `model.ProductID` will be the selected value. Note also that you should be checking the value of `ModelState.IsValid` and if not, repopulate the `SelectList` and return the view.

Comment: When i change this `public string AvailableSizes { get; set; }` to `public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AvailableSizes { get; set; }` in my model i get an error which is Error 3 Assembly 'Ozhay.Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' c:\Users\Naser Dostdar\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Ozhay\Ozhay.Domain\bin\Debug\Ozhay.Domain.dll Ozhay.WebUI

Comment: First, have you done this in a view model (not your data model). Second the error relates to incorrect versions used in your `web.config.cs` file (somewhere in there you have conflicting versions - `Version=5.2.2.0` is not equal to `Version=5.2.3.0`). If you cannot sort it out, then you will need to ask a new question showing the error message and the contents of you `web.config` file because that is going to cause other problems elsewhere in your app.

Comment: Stephen i updated the question where i faced in a sort of problem which didn't paid attention to it, can you please have a look? seriously need your help, thank you

Comment: The code in your edit will work fine although its awful practice. The only thing you would need to do is pass the `SelectList` as a `ViewBag` property and change the view to `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ProductID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.AvailableSizes, ...`. But why would you not want to do this correctly and map your data model to the view model?

Comment: The only thing i can't figure out the code line here, `Product product = repository.Products
                .FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductID == productId);

            return View(product);` logic or concept. I don't know how to do it with the view model? else i am very eager to do it in your way as you know far better than me, thank you

Comment: I'll update my answer shortly to show you the code in the full GET method. But binding your `AvaliableSizes` to a property named `productId` does not make sense (the name of that property suggests its the ID of the product, not the size) so its a bit unclear what you trying to do.

Comment: My best guess is that you have a view to select a product (a dropdownlist?) and to select a size for that product?

Comment: Just to give you a bit clear concept of what i am doing i write these line below: 1. I have a view result in my product controller where it redirect users to a specific product details page.
2. From there when the user saw the details and would like to add the Product to his/her cart then he should select size and on add to cart button click the size should be passed to add to cart action method in  cart controller and then from there to the view of  Cart Index which i'll update the question shortly add the index method. This is the concept

Comment: Exactly that is what i want :) also i'll have some other information displayed for the product as product name, description and etc...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109313/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-naser-dostdar).